# empty file creating in root container while writing file into a blob container

Tags: scala, azure-blob-storage, databricks, azure-databricks

writing the data from data frame to a path
path = rootcontainer/container1 + "/" + fileName
df.repartition(1)
.write
.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header", "true")
.option("delimiter", Delimiter)
.option("quote", "\u0000")
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.save(path)

when executing the above command, it is creating empty blob file (fileName) in rootcontainer/container1 apart from creating the actual file in rootcontainer/container1/fileName

how can we avoid creating empty blob in root folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a regular occurrence in several Azure Blob Storage tools (AZCopy, Data Factory, some Spark jobs, etc.). It stems from the fact that directories/folders don't actually exist in Blob Storage, but are part of a naming convention. As a result, some of these tools create 0 byte artifacts as part of their process to represent those paths. Some tools do a better job than others of cleaning up after themselves, but there really is no way to prevent their generation. Once the operation is complete, you may delete them without consequence.

This is just a guess on my part, but one thing that may help would be using Data Lake Storage instead of traditional Blob Storage.

Comment: Same issue here writing to parquet (also to csv) out of pyspark running in databricks to Azure Blob Storage - 0 byte artifacts show up alongside "folders" in the blob container.  I simply changed the ADF data source to the "folder" instead of empty file, and read everything perfectly